# How to secure unauthorised access in Cloud SQL Database

Tags: google-cloud-sql

My database is hosted in Cloud SQL, and how can I secure my database to from unauthorised entities to access.
How should I protect my database??

PS: I have seen suspicious activity on my database.

Comment: Are you using Cloud SQL MySQL or PostgreSQL? This information might be useful to investigate further and try to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Google has written an extensive blog post on how to secure a database [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/best-practices-for-securing-your-google-cloud-databases).

One of the most important things that you should consider is going by the [Least Access principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). This can be achieved easily by the [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview) tool that Google Cloud Platform has for this.

Also, if your Cloud SQL instance has a public IP, you should consider using [SSL/TLS](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance) to encrypt your data.

Last but not least, if your database was deployed with a default login, you should make it a top priority to change or disable that account.